# How to debug functions in a dynamic library loaded with LD_PRELOAD with gdb?

Tags: c, debugging, gdb, ld-preload

I'm trying to debug some functions in a dynamic shared library libexecHook.so. This library is preloaded setting LD_PRELOAD in order to intercept and rewrite some calls to execve() and friends. For debugging purposes I have built gmake with symbols. From what I read in other questions this should work:

```
gdb ~/tmp/make-dfsg-3.81/make
set exec-wrapper env LD_PRELOAD=/home/marko/execHook.C027/lib/libexecHook.so.0.0.0
start
break execve
break execvp
cont
```

I do see the breakpoints being set properly, e.g.

```
4       breakpoint     keep y   0x00007ffff7bd92e0 in execvp at execHook.c:128
```

but gdb never breaks at my preloaded exec..() functions. Watching the debug output during execution I see that the my library functions are being called.

Comment: Have you tried also setting LD_PRELOAD before launching gdb?

Comment: I hadn't tried it before, but it does not make a difference.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason gdb did not break at my preloaded wrapper functions is that these are executed from a child process to which gdb was not attached. On Linux I can

```
set follow-fork-mode child
```

to make gdb attach to the child that gets created in a `vfork()`.

Answer (score 1):

Try saying `start` before setting your breakpoints.  This will begin running the program which will cause the library dependencies to be satisfied, hopefully using your LD_PRELOAD path.  Then set the breakpoints after start, and then do continue.

Comment: The exact same thing: I see the breakpoints: `4       breakpoint     keep y   0x00007ffff7bd92e0 in execvp at execHook.c:128` and the program's debug output shows that it's using the functions, but the breakpoints are never triggered.